# How to add Data into the Database from VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm new to VB. It's been few weeks since I started learning VB.My question is I'm having difficulty in adding Data in to the Database (I'm using MS Access) from VB. So far I got this code but it isn't running well:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class CraeteAccount
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader


Public Sub btnCreate_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LogIn1.accdb")

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
    Dim str As String
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim Password As String



    If txtPassword.Text = txtRetype.Text Then
        cnn.Open()
        Try
            UserName = txtUserName.Text
            Password = txtPassword.Text

            str = "UPDATE Users SET UserName= '" & UserName & "', Password= '" & Password
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("New User has been Created!")
            cnn.Close()
            Me.Hide()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Occured!")
            cnn.Close()

        End Try
        Me.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox("Check your Password!")
        cnn.Close()
        txtPassword.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

When the code runs It donot add data and quickly goes to catch to show the Message Box which reads "Error Occured". So Can anyone Please Help me?

Comment: Could you show us the contexto of ex.Message?

Comment: What's the *actual exception*?  Exceptions contain very useful information about runtime problems.  Ignoring them makes debugging difficult.

Comment: For the time being, comment out the Try, Catch and End Try lines so that you get to see the actual error message and you can let us know exactly what the error message says - if that doesn't help you solve it.

Comment: You SQL syntax for the OleDBCommand is incorrect. Should be something like `... Username= ?, Password = ? ...`  I think - don't use params myself. Might be other problems.

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance, the SQL query is broken in several ways:

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET UserName= '" & UserName & "', Password= '" & Password
```

---

The first thing to notice is that you're not closing the quotes after the password.  However, even that isn't what you really want to do.  What you want to do is this:

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET UserName=@UserName, Password=@Password"
```

This creates query parameters, which your next two lines are looking to populate with values:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password)
```

Putting user values *directly* into the query is called a SQL injection vulnerability.  It allows users to execute arbitrary code on your database, which is clearly a bad thing.  So you're definitely going to want to stick with using these parameters instead.

---

The second problem here is that this query is going to update *every record int he table*.  So it's basically going to overwrite *all* `Users` records with multiple copies of this one record.

If this *really* should be an `UPDATE` statement when you're going to want to add a `WHERE` clause to it which would identify the *specific* record you want to update.

*However*, I suspect based on the context that this should instead be an `INSERT` statement, since it's *creating* a new record:

```
str = "INSERT INTO Users (UserName, Password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)"
```

---

Additionally, **and this is important**, you are storing user passwords in *plain text*.  This is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users.  You should be obscuring user passwords with a 1-way hash so that they can *never* be retrieved in their original form.  Not even by you as the system administrator.

(The language and emphasis used here may be a bit harsh for a beginner.  Especially if you're working on a purely academic project with no actual users.  But it's seriously that important.  And there's no time like the present to learn about it.)

---

Another issue here is that you're assuming success of the query:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("New User has been Created!")
```

At the very least you should be checking the return value to make sure a record was actually affected:

```
Dim rowsAffected As Int32 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
If rowsAffected > 0 Then
    MsgBox("New User has been Created!")
Else
    'no record was inserted, handle error condition
End If
```

---

Another issue that you're facing, which isn't directly related to your problem but *is* making it much more difficult for you to debug your problem, is that you're ignoring error information:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error Occured!")
    cnn.Close()
```

In this code block the `ex` variable contains all of the information that the .NET Framework can give you about the error that took place.  What you're basically doing is replacing all of that diagnostic information (error message, stack trace, etc.) with a single custom error message that contains no information.

Best not to do that.

---

Note that, given these issues, there may very well be other problems with the code.  But this should at least get you going for a bit.

Comment: Considering OP is a fresh beginner in VB this answer is quite considerate and informative in the basics of database updates, user password storage, SQL injection, and exception handling.

Comment: Hi, well actually it isn't saving into the data base. When the above steps are followed Database If statement doesn't run and the Database remains unchanged.

Comment: @DarkHorse: When you step through the code in a debugger, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: Upvote for addressing the security issues. Far too many developers ignore these critical concepts.

Comment: @Sylverac: The funny part is that the OP was already adding the parameters, just didn't have the placeholders for them in the query.  I've never seen that happen before :)

Comment: @David The program run well without any problem. But the issue is that data was not saved in the database.

Comment: @DarkHorse: You're going to have to be more specific.  Which will likely include updating the question with your new code and explaining the debugging steps you've taken and any information you have about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're simultaneously trying to concatenate an update statement with user input (bad) and using parameterized values (good).  Try

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET UserName=@UserName, Password=@Password"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password)
```

But this still won't work because this update statement will update all the records in the database with these values.  Are you trying to update an existing record or create a new one?  If you're updating an existing one, you need a WHERE clause; if you're trying to create a new one, you need to use INSERT instead.

Comment: The program ran well but the data is not saved in the database.